# virtuemart template override doesn't work

Tags: virtuemart

I am overriding a particular template  so according to rules the data is in html folder 
 and in virtuemart configuration setting the default view is selected properly 
 as the template name , but still the overriding doesn't work?

Comment: What file are you overriding, and where do you place it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the modified file in template folder under: `/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/`.

Let's say that you want to modify this file:

> /components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php

You have to copy it to:

> /templates/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php

Reference: [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)